# how to iterate each row of CSV data using ForEach?

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, foreach, read-eval-print-loop

Looking to use `ForEach` here specifically.

---

reading in and loading a `csv` file for sample data:

```
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $a = Import-Csv  -Path ./alphabet.csv
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $a[7].psobject.Properties.name
symbol
code word
morse code
phonetic
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $a[7].'code word'             
Hotel
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $a.'code word'   
Alfa/Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
Hotel
India
Juliett
Kilo
..
Yankee
Zulu
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> $numbers=(1,2,3,4,5)
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> 
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex> foreach ($number in $numbers){ echo $number}
1
2
3
4
5
PS /home/nicholas/powershell/regex>
```

but how would `foreach` be used to iterate through each row?  Something like:

```
$a.forEach($code_word in $a.'code word'){echo $code_word}
```

looking to use `ForEach` here specifically, preferably in one-line which can be used in the REPL console.

Comment: the `.ForEach()` method does NOT work that way. [*grin*] you need to put the entire thing into the `()`. that is why most folks start it as `.ForEach({})` ... to make the need for such habitual.

Comment: Just use `foreach` _keyword_: `foreach($code_word in $a.'code word'){ $code_word }`. Note that `echo` is superfluous, a variable statement will be output automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two instances of Foreach in Powershell.  One is a keyword, and the other is an alias for Foreach-object.  The easiest way to loop through a csv file is to import-csv, send the result through the pipeline, and use Foreach-Object to introduce the loop.  The special symbol "%" is also shorthand for Foreach-Object.

Try this:

```
Import-csv -path myfile.csv |
    Foreach-object {
      $sym = $_.symbol
      $code = $_.'code word'
      "The code word for $sym is $code"
    }
```

On this csv file.

```
symbol,code word,morse code,phonetic
A,Alfa/Alpha,"● ▬",AL FAH
B,Bravo,"▬ ● ● ●",BRAH VOH
C,Charlie,"▬ ● ▬ ●",CHAR LEE
D,Delta,"▬ ● ●",DELL TAH
E,Echo,"●",ECK OH
F,Foxtrot,"● ● ▬ ●",FOKS TROT
G,Golf,"▬ ▬ ●",GOLF
Z,Zulu,"▬ ▬ ▬ ▬ ▬",ZOO LOO
H,Hotel,"● ● ● ●",HOH TELL
```